# basic html/php/jquery gui

Tags: jquery, function

I'm looking to put together a gui with html and php to load data from a directory.

I'd like to have a link on a side menu bar load data from .php files in into a  in the main body area but I don't fully understand how to do it yet. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="common/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<!-- Functions -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function dataSelect(proj) {
        alert(proj.id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "core/catalogue.php?p="+proj,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#dataSelect").html(html);
                }
        });
    }            
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <div id="topheader">
        <div class="logo">
        <div class="head"> Whatever </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="body_area">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="left_menutop"></div>
            <div class="left_menu_area">
                <div class="left_menu_title">Projects:</div>
                <div align="right">
                    <a href="#" class="left_menu" id="someProject" onclick="dataSelect(this)">Some Project</a><br />
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="midarea" id="body">
            <div class="body_textarea">
                <div align="justify" id="dataSelect"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: could you elaborate more on your question.

Comment: I was looking to load data into the "dataSelect" div when a link on the menubar was selected. Right after I made this post I pulled my head out of my a$$ and figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

here's the code that works if anyone else out there is looking to accomplish the same thing:

```
<!-- Functions -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".left_menu").click(function(){
        val = this.id;      
        $.ajax({
            url: "core/catalogue.php?p="+this.id,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#dataSelect").html(html);
                }
        });
    });//end $(".left_menu").click

});//end $(document).ready
</script>
</head>
```